# My Ethereum Solidity automatically connects to parity, how do I switch it to Metamask?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, parity, remix, metamask

I want to run on a test network using metamask but Solidity IDE auto connects to my real parity wallet. How can I switch that?

Comment: Disable the parity chrome extension and enable metamask. Wondering why you prefer one over the other?

Comment: @5chdn still wondering? ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Remix/Browser-Solidity:

1. In the right-hand settings panel select "Contract".
2. Under "Environment" select "Injected Web3".

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask and the Parity browser extension don't work well together, since they both attempt to inject the web3 API, so whichever one loads first gets over-written.

You'll have to:

1. Right-click one of the extension icons in your browser toolbar.
2. Select "Manage Extensions"
3. Uncheck the one you don't want to use so it is not "active".